# How can I have JMockit not mock a certain method?

Tags: java, jmockit

I have a class that contains the following method, which I do not expect to ever return null:

```
public String getAutoSaveDir() {
    if (autoSaveDir == null || autoSaveDir.isEmpty()) {
        return System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    } else {
        return autoSaveDir;
    }
}
```

I need to mock this class with `@Injectable` for other reasons.* Unfortunately, this means that this method returns null:

```
@Tested
private MyClass myClass;

@Injectable
private ClassContainingMethod classContainingMethod;

@Test
public void myTest() {
    // Calls classContainingMethod.getAutoSaveDir()
    myClass.saveFile();
}
```

This unfortunately fails, as `getAutoSaveDir()` returns null. I confirmed that `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` does not return null, so it seems that JMockit is mocking the method to return null, when I don't want it to.

I am aware that I can set up an `Expectations` block to tell it to just return `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`, but it seems really silly to mock it to return something that it would be returning anyway if unmocked.

How can I have JMockit not mock this method?

I am using JMockit 1.22 (would love to use a later version, but we have several instances of mocking private methods, which isn't allowed in later versions).

---

* I have to use @Injectable because the field is annotated with @Autowired. If I try to use a real instance, I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing @Injectable for field MyClass#classContainingMethod, of type com.example.ClassContainingMethod`

Comment: Well, you basically want to *partially* mock the class, and partial mocking is a JMockit feature (see Tutorial). But why mock it at all in the first place? Can't a real instance be used?

Comment: @Rogério Unfortunately, the real class is annotated with `@Autowired`, so I get an error if it's not `@Injectable.

Comment: Use `@Tested(fullyInitialized = true)`.